# How to generate assets manifest using CLI?

Tags: angular, webpack, hash, command-line-interface, assets

During build Angular generates hashes for asset files. In other projects I used to us webpack-manifest-plugin for generating a manifest file which contained mapping between original filename and hashed version, but Angular doesn't allow installing plugins. Is there any other way to achieve a  mapping? I'm using --output-hashing none as a workaround but I'd like to keep hashing feature.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The project had ended up with hashing disabled.